# Using scope to sort entries in related child models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-models

I have three related models such as the following, each being the child of the one above:

```
class Course < ActiveRecord::Base 
  has_many :questions 
end 

class Question < ActiveRecord::Base 
  belongs_to :course
  has_many: :answers

  default_scope order: 'questions.created_at DESC'
  scope :by_answer_count, -> { #orders Questions based on its answer count
    joins(:answers).reorder("count(answers.id) DESC").group(:id)
  }
end 

class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base 
  belongs_to :question
end
```

What I am having trouble figuring out is: how do I use my scope method `by_answer_count`, which is in my `Question` model, to order the list of **courses** I show by the most number of answers to the least in the `index` action of `CoursesController`? Is there a way to utilize that, or should I write a 2 layers down scope method in my `CoursesController` to get the filter to work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to use [merge](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/SpawnMethods/merge) to get that to work.

```
class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :by_answer_count, joins(:questions).merge(Question.by_answer_count)
end
```

**Edit**

It appears that there is a bug in the way that merge works.  https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/3002

You can work around it by adding a relation from course to answers.  So your Course class would look like this:

```
class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :answers, through: :questions
  scope :by_answer_count, joins(:questions).merge(Question.by_answer_count)
end
```

Another option is to use a manual joins clause in your Question class.

```
joins("answers ON answers.question_id = questions.id").reorder(...)
```

Comment: This seemed like it should work.. however, I get the error "Association named 'answers' was not found; perhaps you misspelled it?"  But strange since this previously worked when put into my `QuestionsController`.  Just to make sure, I am calling the function via `Course.by_answer_count`

Comment: There is a bug in ActiveRecord::Relation#merge.  See my updates for workarounds.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should set a counter_cache on your association. Like Ryan Bates suggests in one of his first screencasts: http://railscasts.com/episodes/23-counter-cache-column

I think the following would work:

```
Course.joins(:questions).order('questions.answer_count DESC')
```

Or scope:

```
scope :most_answered, joins(:questions).order('questions.answer_count DESC')
```

It would also have the benefit of being a single query. I didn't test but it should work.

Comment: Thanks - I looked into counter_cache and its seems like a great feature (and could get things done with far less code).  Will do this for my question/answer models.